# xcode 4.5 crash log symbolicates except for app lines

Tags: xcode, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

How to I get to symbolicate everything?

Here is an example so what I am talking about:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x351642cc CFRelease + 32
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3518e130 CFArraySetValueAtIndex + 284
2   AddressBook                     0x32971aba ABCMultiValueReplaceLabel + 58
3   AddressBook                     0x3298c598 ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex + 140
4   My App                      0x00011206 0x00011206
5   My App                      0x00010e48 0x00010e48
6   My App                      0x00011ada 0x00011ada
7   My App                      0x0001027c 0x0001027c
8   My App                      0x0000ecf2 0x0000ecf2
9   My App                      0x00012f44 0x00012f44
10  My App                      0x00012e3e 0x00012e3e
11  Foundation                      0x32d0aef2 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 14
12  Foundation                      0x32c4a9ec -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 196
13  Foundation                      0x32c4a908 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
14  CFNetwork                       0x3111c5dc ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 24
15  CFNetwork                       0x3111bcc8 ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 52
16  CFNetwork                       0x31144130 ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 16
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3516974a CFArrayApplyFunction + 174
18  CFNetwork                       0x3114458e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 70
19  CFNetwork                       0x310a815a MultiplexerSource::perform() + 186
20  CoreFoundation                  0x351f8680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
21  CoreFoundation                  0x351f7ee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
22  CoreFoundation                  0x351f6cb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
23  CoreFoundation                  0x35169eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
24  CoreFoundation                  0x35169d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
25  GraphicsServices                0x356a62e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
26  UIKit                           0x365482fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
27  My App                      0x0000275a 0x0000275a
28  My App                      0x00002714 0x00002714
```

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You might find these links useful on how to symbolicate crash logs:
[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)
[iOS Crash Logs](http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html)

Another way: in Xcode 4.5, set your build target (via the Scheme drop down next to the Stop button) to an iOS Device. Then go to the Product menu in the menu bar and choose Archive.

Next, open the Organizer window (Window menu in the menu bar --> Organizer), and make sure your app shows up in the list when you click the Archives icon at the top of the Organizer window.

Finally, click the Devices icon at the top of the Organizer window, click Device Logs on the left under Library, and drag your crash log into the pane on the right. It should be fully auto-symbolicated for you.